# consulta para obtener fecha maxima entre varias tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Es posible obtener la fecha más reciente entre varias tablas, dado el id de una tabla principal que está en todas las demás tablas? ¿Cómo podría obtener esto?

Tabla 1 principal

```
id_tabla1 
descripcion
```

tabla 2

```
id_tabla2
fecha
fk_tabla1
```

tabla 3

```
id_tabla3
fecha
fk_tabla1
```

tabla 4

```
id_tabla4
fecha
fk_tabla1
```

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
select MAX(Fecha) as fecha 
  from tabla1 
 INNER JOIN tabla2 on tabla1.id_tabla1 = tabla2.id_tabla1 
 GROUP BY tabla1.id_tabla1
```

Pero esa es la fecha más reciente de `tabla2`. ¿Cómo podría comparar luego con las demás y tener la más reciente de entre todas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una idea es que hagas un join de todas las tablas, haciendo el max de cada fecha, y luego usando [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) para devolver el máximo de todos los máximos:

```
select greatest(
         coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0)) as max_fecha
  from tabla1 t1
  left join tabla2 t2
    on t2.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla3 t3
    on t3.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla4 t4
    on t4.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
```

**Edición**

Me acabo de dar cuenta que en tu consulta incluyes `GROUP BY tabla1.id_tabla1`, lo que parece indicar que quieres la fecha máxima *por `id_tabla1`*. Si ese es el caso, simplemente agrégale la claúsula `GROUP BY` a la consulta:

```
select t1.id_tabla1,
       greatest(
         coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0)) as max_fecha
  from tabla1 t1
  left join tabla2 t2
    on t2.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla3 t3
    on t3.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla4 t4
    on t4.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
 group by t1.id_tabla1
```

**Edición 2**

Si quieres saber de cual tabla salió el valor máximo, es un poco mas complicado, pero se puede, usando una expresión `CASE`:

```
select t1.id_tabla1,
       greatest(
         coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
         coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0)) as max_fecha,
       case when max(t2.fecha) = greatest(
                                   coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0))
            then 'TABLA2'
            when max(t3.fecha) = greatest(
                                   coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0))
            then 'TABLA3'
            when max(t4.fecha) = greatest(
                                   coalesce(max(t2.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t3.fecha), 0), 
                                   coalesce(max(t4.fecha), 0))
            then 'TABLA4'
       end as nombre_tabla
  from tabla1 t1
  left join tabla2 t2
    on t2.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla3 t3
    on t3.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
  left join tabla4 t4
    on t4.fk_tabla1 = t1.id_tabla1
 group by t1.id_tabla1
```

Por supuesto, cabe la posibilidad de que el valor máximo sea el mismo en más de una tabla. En ese caso, te devolverá una de las tablas.

Comment: Genial lo de `greatest`. Me encantaría que estuviera en SQL Server.

Comment: No conocía de esta función. Muy buena.

Comment: genial gracias sstan la respuesta fue totalmente asertiva :D

Comment: solo una preguntilla mas, puesto que la query ya funciono... si es posible? podria retornar el nombre de la tabla a la que pertenece dicha fecha

Comment: Se puede. Agregué una edición a la respuesta para que veas.

Comment: muchas gracias sstan por las respuestas muy acertivas, pero me acabo de dar cuenta de algo nose si es posible solucionarlo.. si el id_tabla1 solo es foranea en una de las tablas ya sea la tabla2,tabla3 o la tabla4 cualqiera de ellas, me devuelbe null, por lo que tiene que tener al menos un registro en las 3 tablas, sin embargo si solo esta en una sola me tendria q devolber esa fecha, aunque tenga muchos registros en solo esa tabla velbolver la mayor de ellas. muchas gracias de antemano por la colaboracion

Comment: @Alex: Cierto. Hay que usar coalesce para evitar este problema. Modifiqué la respuesta nuevamente para que veas.  De ser necesario, puedes cambiar `coalesce(..., 0)` por `coalesce(..., 'una fecha bien antigua')`.

Comment: ya la probe sstan y si ahora controla eso, pero por alguna razon, en la tabla1 tengo 3 registro y el primero no devuelbe el nombre de la tabla si muestra la fecha mayor pero no el nombre de la tabla ala que pertence, los demas registro si.. todo perfecto :) ahi algo que se puede hacer con ese problema? y con eso daria por concluida la pregunta ya que lo demas esta perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: @Alex: Fue un error de mi parte. En la expresión `CASE`, estaba haciendo la comparación `when t2.fecha = greatest(...)`, cuando tenía que ser mas bien `when max(t2.fecha) = greatest(...)`. Modifiqué la respuesta una vez más para corregir el error.

Comment: @sstan: muchas gracias por todo, funciona de 10 te lo agradezco mucho :D

Comment: @sstan puedo utilizar este ejemplo, para obtener el mismo resultado pero esta vez de un id especifico como parametro por ejemplo: del id '1' la fecha max y el nombre de la tabla de solo ese id? tendria que aumentar un where?

Comment: @sstan y el caso de que las tabla2, tabla3 y tabla4 tengan un atributo mas, por ejemplo descripcion, puedo mostrar en la consulta ese valor tambien dependiendo de la tabla en la que se obtubo la mayer fecha?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres saber la fecha máxima entre todas las tablas no puedes hacer un join entre ellas. En su lugar, deberías obtener las fechas de todas ellas y obtener el valor máximo. Para esto, haces uso de `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT MAX(T.fecha) AS 'Fecha_maxima'
FROM (
    SELECT fecha
    FROM tabla2 t2
      INNER JOIN tabla1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.fk_tabla1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT fecha
    FROM tabla3 t3
      INNER JOIN tabla1 t1 ON t1.id = t3.fk_tabla1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT fecha
    FROM tabla4 t4
      INNER JOIN tabla1 t1 ON t1.id = t4.fk_tabla1
) T;
```

Comment: tengo un error de sintaxis en el from? que podria ser..

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca al ejecutar el query?